# Templating in Haml questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Okay, please don't down grade me for this question. I have been using Haml along with hammer app for mac to process my haml files into html. I really have been loving it so far. Now my question is I wanted to get into templates with haml/rails. Do I need to have ruby installed on my unit to do this or could I simple render files in haml with hammer app?

I've seen the code something like this:

//haml code
= render :partial => "(some file name)"

but I get a "for has not been defined" error.

Is it at all possible to use partial just by using hammer app or do I need to install ruby?

I an very new at this.

Comment: the `haml-rails` gem is for using Haml in Rails apps. If you're not using Rails, don't use it. And if you're not using Ruby, you definitely aren't using Rails.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use rails but needed to know if that had Ruby installed or not in hammer. Tried contacting the dev but no response.

Comment: I've never used Hammer, but if you want to use Haml with Rails ditch Hammer. Hammer is just going to be another moving part. Once you understand how Rails works with Haml, you might be able to shoehorn in Hammer somewhere - it wasn't obvious to me from reading the Hammer docs how you could, or if doing so would provide any benefit.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is this http://hammerformac.com/docs/tags/includes

Comment: Thanks phoet. I figured out how to get the includes to work with hammer. removed .html and only used .haml as my ext.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks phoet. I figured out how to get the includes to work with hammer. removed .html and only used .haml as my extension file name.